# Where to put Settings button in App with endless list scrolling

Tags: gui-design, android, ios

I am currently working on an App for both iOS and Android for phones.
The main screen of the app has a header with the option to select different feeds. Below is a list that has endless scrolling to display the content of the feed.

The original design idea was to put the Settings button in the header next to the feed selection and the search icon. However, the customer decided against it because settings are not very important and should not be in the header. At the bottom of the list is also not an option because the list continues to scroll.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 5):

The Settings should be in the header.
Look at the [Google Material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) structure as a reference.

A 3-dot menu doesn't take up too much space.

[image]
[image]

Comment: However, depending on the content of the overflow menu, and the existence of the Hamburger Menu, Settings could also be placed in the Hambuerger menu. If you have no other options in the overflow menu, but you have a Navigation Drawer, put it there. For example, see http://cdn.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/nexus2cee_135.png

Answer (score 0):

For Android it's probably best to place a settings item within a 3-dot menu in the top right corner. However for iOS it's much more fair game. You could have a slide out right hand side menu with secondary links such as settings.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many feed there are to be chosen from, you could also insert the settings link below the feeds in a separated area (maybe your customer also wants to display terms of use or other "not important" information.)

SELECT FEED
- Feed 1
- Feed 2
- Feed 3
etc.
- MORE
- Settings

Just a thought, maybe it helps.